# How to convert a dateTime object into a string in asp . net c#

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

Have to add the data from excel file to SQL Server by using ClosedXML Library, One of my column is a dateTime object,

```cs
DateTime IdentificationDate = worksheet.Cell(i, 6).Value.ToString();
```

I tried using parceExcat function, but not working.

Comment: What did you try for "ParseExact" and in wat way was it "not working" (please show code and exact error message)? What *is* the exact value of `worksheet.Cell(i, 6).Value.ToString()`?

Comment: Usually the problems with ParseExact start from a format string not correctly matching  the input value. So, if you don't tell us exactly what is the input value and what is the format string that you used in the ParseExact call, it is only a guessing game. Please add these details to your question

Comment: Dates having the format as 12/19/2022, will be the value of                        
worksheet.Cell(i, 6).Value.ToString() @HansKeﬆing

Comment: Is that the format as shown in Excel, of really the result of the ToString()? So what did you use as format? I expect that `M/d/yyyy` should work. Do you really need that ToString? What is really in that `.Value` property (use the debugger to find out)?

Answer (score 1):

You can set/have that format, and convert to a date like this:

```
        string s = @"12/19/2022";

        DateTime dtBook = DateTime.ParseExact(s, "MM/dd/yyyy", null);
        Debug.Print($"Month = {dtBook.Month}");
        Debug.Print($"Day = {dtBook.Day}");
        Debug.Print($"Year = {dtBook.Year}");

        string strSQL =
            @"INSERT INTO tblHotelsB (FirstName, LastName, BookingDate)
             VALUES(@FN, @LN, @BookingDate)";

        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.TEST4))
        {
            using(SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand(strSQL, conn))
            {
                cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@FN", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = tFN.Text;
                cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@LN", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = tLN.Text;
                cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@BookingDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = dtBook;
                conn.Open();
                cmdSQL.ExecuteNonQuery();   
            }
        }
    }
```

output:

```
Month = 12
Day = 19
Year = 2022
```

And the sample insert code thus should work fine.